# How put DESC numbering before post title wordpress friendly with page navigation?

Tags: php, wordpress

I put a number before the post title in Wordpress and number ordering is desc.

This code in my theme's index.php:

```
<div id="content">
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : $post_nr = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php echo $post_nr--;?>. Book Title: <span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>. Writer: <?php the_tags(' '); ?>. Publisher: <?php the_category(', '); ?>. </span>
        </div>      
   <?php endwhile;  ?>
   <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

My problem, it's code does not function if I use page navigation. If I click page2, page3, ..., it's numbering don't show real total post.

Any help me, please. What code should I add and placed where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work properly, we need:

- The current post position
- Total amount of posts
- Amount of posts per page
- The current page we are on

Lets look at a possible function to achieve this

```
function get_post_position_in_reverse()
{
    // Invoke the global $wp_query object
    global $wp_query;

    // Make sure that we are actually inside the loop, if not, bail
    if ( !in_the_loop() )
        return false;

    //Setup our variables we will be using
    // Get the current page we are on
    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
        $current_page = 1; 
    }

    // Get the current post's position plus 1 as post counter starts at 0
    $post_position = $wp_query->current_post + 1;
    // Get the total amount of posts in the query
    $total_posts   = $wp_query->found_posts;
    // Get the amount of posts_per_page from backend
    $ppp           = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    /**
     * Now that we have everything set up, we need to do the maths
     *
     * If we have 20 posts across 4 pages with 6 posts per page, we will have
     * 6 posts on pages 1,2 and 3 and only 2 posts on page 4. Our post numbers
     * will be as follow, the first post on page one will be 20 and the last
     * post on page 4 will be 1
     */
    $number = $total_posts - ( ( $current_page * $ppp ) - ( $ppp - $post_position ) ) + 1;

    return number_format_i18n( $number );
}
```

You can now add it anywhere inside the loop as follow

```
echo get_post_position_in_reverse();
```

Comment: If want ASC or normal numbering, REPLACE --> $number = $total_posts - ( ( $current_page * $ppp ) - ( $ppp - $post_position ) ) + 1; WITH --> $number = ( $current_page * $ppp ) - ( $ppp - $post_position ) ;

Answer (score 1):

Try function instead of query

```
$post_nr = wp_count_posts();
```

Comment: Thank for Trushel Patel. I try replace <?php if ( have_posts() ) : $post_nr = $wp_query->post_count; ?> with <?php if ( have_posts() ) : $post_nr = wp_count_posts(); ?>, still problem.